# How would I make debian package with dsc with dpkg --build?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging, deb

I am using `dpkg --build <package name>` in order to build packages. The packages are working properly with `dpkg -I <package name>`. In order to make them work with `apt-get` I need `package_name.dsc` file, which is not possible to get with `dpkg --build` command.

I do not know how to build packages with `debuild` or `dpkg-buildpackage`. Can any one tell is there any simple way to do this, as it `*.dsc` file is simple text file can I generate it by some other tool.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1624438

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to generate a .dsc package, you should be using the `debuild -S` command.

Assuming you are building packages on Ubuntu, you should consult [this Ubuntu guide about packaging](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html).

It will help you get started and point out how you can use other parameters of `debuild` to build a .dsc package among others.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using Debhelper. There are many tutorials out there on how to learn debhelper packaging; you can find a pretty good recent one along with some complementary material here: http://www.lucas-nussbaum.net/blog/?p=676

It is possible to assemble bare binary debs from a simple directory, as you are doing, but their usefulness is quite limited, since they are difficult to reproduce, port, maintain, autobuild, and generally violate all sorts of Debian/Ubuntu policies.